# I want to retrieve messages from an instagram business account with facebook graph api

Tags: python

I want to retrieve messages from an instagram business account with facebook graph api.
I wrote /conversations?platform=instagram&user_id=<> at graph api explorer

but i got this error

{
"error": {

```
"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field 
  (conversations) on node type (IGUser)",

"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "AlEYWTam1eySwW4pO1jUWT1"
```

}
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqC0u.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.